# How to make the BGM not stop between scenes?

Tags: unity, music

I want my background music to keep playing on loop, but whenever I transition into another scene, the loop starts over.

Is there any way to have the scene record the last point of the music it plays, and in the next scene starts playing at that moment?

Comment: or don't make the BGM part of the scene

Comment: @ratchetfreak how so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it myself by making an Empty Object (BGM) where to place the music. Then, haivng a simple script attached to the object with the following code:

```
void Awake(){
     DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```

And it became a persistent object, therefore it's not destroyed between scenes.

Comment: Keep in mind if you add your BGM object to every scene while testung you will have duplicates! Make sure that those components are singeltons or you will run out of memory.

Comment: @CodeClown yeah, I'm taking that into consideration. Thank you :)